# Joomla, how get component id in plugin using component name

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have created plugin in group content. Now i want to fetch component or extension id using component name.

I am using below code

```
$com_articles = JTable::getInstance( 'component');
$com_articles->loadByOption('com_directory');
```

But error log showing error

```
[09-Nov-2016 09:41:01 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function loadByOption() on boolean in /home/phprilpk/public_html/demo/refer/plugins/content/auto_menu/auto_menu.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions are stored in prefix_extensions table in database. You can get extension data using jFactory::getDBO();

See this code.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$com_articles = $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__extensions WHERE name = 'com_directory'");
$com_articles = $com_articles->loadObject();
print_r($com_articles);
```

Comment: How do i get id from this object?

Comment: $com_articles->extension_id this will print id